# How to handle time series in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to add the following sort of data (can be any number of such pairs under 1000) to the newly introduced timeseries chart in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library

```
Value :  50.0   at   1472112259
Value :  49.0   at   1472112294
Value :  50.0   at   1472112329
Value :  50.0   at   1472112360
Value :  50.0   at   1472112392
```

The following data will be fetched from the array. 
Right now, I guess there is some mess up with the timestamps.
Here is the complete code: https://gist.github.com/utkarshns/e1723dcc57022fcd392bc3b127b6c898

UNIX timestamps will be parsed to required time format after I can successfully add values to the graph.

Currently, the problem I face is that the timestamps probably get clipped and values are overwritten which leads to a pretty messed up graph with really weird x-axis values.

Update:
Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCmHu.jpg

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: one second, I will update the question with the screenshot

Comment: I've looked at the first screenshot, and everything seems to be fine to me there. What, exactly, is the issue you have?

Comment: The x-axis values are separated merely by 1 or 2 seconds and that is so wrong.

Also, over here https://gist.github.com/utkarshns/e1723dcc57022fcd392bc3b127b6c898#file-java-L133

This condition has to be there, otherwise the graph is really messed up.
I will add that screenshot as well

Comment: Screenshot added in imgur album, the graph is with 100 values, without the condition in line 133

Comment: Added another screenshot with 100 values and with the condition in line 133

Comment: Yes, I see now, thanks! Can you post your axis formatter, please? Or are you using the one from the MPAndroidChart example?

Comment: I was using the one from the example, even if i dont use the formatter.
The timeseries nature is all messed up, why so?

Comment: Had similar issue with time-stamp. The problem is that Entry x value is float and time-stamp is just to big value so some seconds could be inaccurate.

Comment: Exactly, I tried integer, it can easily hold the timestamps. Even then I am having the same problem.
Nearby timestamps are so inaccurate that they come out to be the same value, which overwrites the previous value creating a havoc.
Really weird datatype issue, float failing on some level.

Comment: Yes, indeed my friend. My solution to you would be adding indexes in your Entries instead of timestamp and creating separateList with timestamp `BigDecimal` is good for that. And in your ValueFormatter just use index and take `BigDecimal` value from List

Comment: Ok, I will try that and post a solution here itself!
Thanks

Comment: @VygintasB
My timestamps arent evenly separated, i want the x-axis distances to be according to the time gap. So indices wont work in my case.
Will contact Philip probably.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Float values can't hold very big numbers and still be accurate, so you need a separate List with these timestamp values. `BigDecimal` should be ok for this purpose. Your distances must be in accordance to the time gaps between your events. Just iterate from the start date to end date keeping count of how many timestamps you have and add Entry with count from the timestamps you wish your value to be.

```
Long myValues[] = {1472112259L, 1472112294L, 1472112329L, 1472112360L, 1472112392L};// your values

   ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();// Entry List
   Long start = 1472112259L;//start
   Long end = 1472112392L;//end
   List<BigDecimal> mList = new ArrayList<>(); //Decimal list which holds timestamps
   int count = 0;

   for (Long i = start; i <= end; i++) {

       mList.add(new BigDecimal(i));
       if (myValues.equals(i)) {
           values.add(new Entry(count, 50));
       }
       count++;//always increment
   }
```

And your ValueFormatter should look like this:

```
AxisValueFormatter() {

    private FormattedStringCache.Generic<Long, Date> mFormattedStringCache = new FormattedStringCache.Generic<>(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"));
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue ( float value, AxisBase axis){

            return mFormattedStringCache.getFormattedValue(new Date(mList.get((int)value).longValueExact()*1000), value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits () {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you have any question or something is unclear I'll be happy to help.

Comment: can you tell where you use mList and what it is used for? I have a feeling that timeline visualiztions need axes that are not only labeled, but also ordered as well as give keep distance information (point at 8:30 is far away from 10:30). Or is the latter not important?

Comment: Pont of using mList is to hold timestamps because MpChart uses Float values which is not enough to hold timestamps

Comment: Hi Vygintas, thanks a lot for the answer. If the point of using mList ist to hold the timestamp values, why do you have so many of them? is it not enough to hold 5 values?

Comment: @arthur I mean Float value cant hold enough digits, so formated dates are inacurate

Comment: That float is inaccurate, I fully agree. Hence you need to save bigDecimal objects. Do you need to save 5 bigDecimal objects or a lot more? 133 in your case, I believe

Comment: @arthur Cehck this Answer If I'm not mistaken it should help with your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665464/mpandroid-date-formatting-and-parsing-loses-precision/54665649#54665649