# MPAndroid Date Formatting and Parsing Loses Precision

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroid library for the graph of my android app. I have a long value inputted to the entry. My problem is that when I format the values of x axis, it uses float value instead of long so it loses precision.

Here is my code for the entry to the graph:

```
String dateString = "02/13/2019(11:23:45)";
long readingDate = 0;
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy(kk:mm:ss)", Locale.US);
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    readingDate = date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
SensorData.add(new Entry(readingDate, 1.5);
```

Here is my code for formatting the x axis:

```
private class XAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy(kk:mm:ss)", Locale.US).format(value);
        return dateString;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solutions would be to make your first point hold 0 value.

Basically you need subtract start_timestamp from every new x value of `Entry` so chart will be started from 0 value and not of timestamp.

**For example**.

Let's assume `start_timestamp` variable holds your first timestamp of datapoints.

To add new entry use:

`SensorData.add(new Entry(readingDate - start_timestamp, 1.5);`

To format x value you just add start_timestamp to provided x value.

Answer (score 0):

Detailing the great Vygintas B's solution:

```java
private static long timestampStart = 0;
...
for loop-to-fill-dataset {
  if (MyClass.timestampStart == 0)
    MyClass.timestampStart = readingDate;  // the timestamp/epoch
  readingDate -= MyClass.timestampStart;  // first one will be 0 (following ones, the difference to zeroed)
  // and then add to Entry(readingDate, y_value)
...

private class XAxisValueFormatter ... {
@Override
public String getFormattedValue(final float value) {
  final long timestamp = (long)value + MyClass.timestampStart;
  ...
```